# How to implement login screen in iOS (Screenshot attached)

Tags: ios

I have a design for an iOS app that has what looks like a table cell that is editable.[image: Login Screen]

How would I go about implementing and email and password fields? I don't want to make the login screen one big table view controller, but should I use table views or text fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can get something very similar by using two UITextFields and changing the border style. However, if this doesn't work for you, you can always put an image in the background that looks exactly like what you want, and simply hide the border on the text fields.